# Bazel: The following packages have unmet depencies: node-browserslist: depends: nodejs:any, unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, ubuntu, bazel

I am trying to install Bazel on linux (so that I can use the "bazel build" command with some tensorflow libraries) by running

```
sudo apt install bazel-bootstrap
```

However, I am getting the following:
[image: error message]

So far I have tried:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
sudo apt install nodejs-dev
sudo apt install node-gyp
sudo apt install npm
```

However, I got similar errors from running these commands.

I am unsure what I should try next - I know that I have npm and nodejs already installed so I am unsure why I would get that error in the first place.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!